# How to extend root disk

Tags: disk-space-utilization

Trying to figure out how to take from the 200G disk at `/dev/sde` and add that to `root`...or maybe the way to say it is how do I extend `/` into `/dev/sde`?

I've only ever dealt with lvm before or at least disks that have partitions that can be extended.  I'm not sure why there isn't a `part` type for `/`.

```
[root@blah ~]# lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0  514M  0 disk
└─sda1             8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot
sdb                8:16   0    2G  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc                8:32   0   14G  0 disk /
sdd                8:48   0  250G  0 disk
└─sdd1             8:49   0  250G  0 part
  └─vgBackup-VMs 253:0    0  250G  0 lvm  /VMs
sde                8:64   0  200G  0 disk /VM0
sr0               11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: sde is not sda and aslong no lvm has been used you can only move specific folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure why there isn't a part type for /.

There is no partition, that's a file system on the entire disk. [Which is fine on Linux, but confusing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14017/86954) to humans and partitioning software.

LVM can be on entire disks too. PV /dev/sdd1 could have been /dev/sdd.

For disks which can be extended, make those bigger.  Then resize file system.  That's it, no annoying partition step.

Or, you can add additional file systems as new storage, and mount them where space is needed, perhaps /var.

Whether it is possible to steal from other disks depends on the storage system and file system. For example, XFS cannot be reduced. A simple way to reduce XFS is to destroy it, recreate the volume smaller, and restore from backup. And stealing from another block device, without LVM or software RAID, only makes sense for storage arrays or virtual disks sharing the same storage pool.